# What is the difference between 嘗試，試圖，and 企圖?

Tags: meaning, difference, traditional-characters

I'm trying to translate this sentence to Mandarin:

> She's trying to recover the torn photo.

So I was trying to find a meaning of "to try" in Pinpin Dictionary, and I came up with three different words, “嘗試”，“試圖”，and “企圖”. All of them mean "to try".

1. Are there any difference between these words?
2. Based on the context, which one is more appropriate?

   > 1. 她**嘗試**修復被碎照片。
   > 2. 她**試圖**修復被碎照片。
   > 3. 她**企圖**修復被碎照片。

Comment: use online dict e.g. bkrs:  **尝试** #4400  try  attempt try one's hand at

你尝试过写小说吗? Have you ever tried your hand at writing a novel?
**企图**  #2703 attempt; seek; try:
企图东山再起 attempt (try) to stage a comeback
企图行凶 offer violence
企图杀人灭口 seek to kill all so that there won't be any eye-witness left
囚犯们企图逃跑，但是失败了。 The prisoners attempted to escape but failed.
他们企图杀他。 They sought to kill him.
 
**试图**  #3902 try; attempt; intend 打算
试图表明存在一种真正的科学语言
敌人试图突围, 但没有得逞试图逃跑 make attempt at escaping
我在试图游到对岸去时差一点被淹死。他试图偷越国境。 attempted to cross  border illegally.  & much more, conclude 1,2 ok

Comment: That's interesting. Looks like "企圖" is more used in negative meanings, "trying to steal, trying to kill". That means "企圖" is not appropriate in this context. But I saw one of your sentence `他**试图**偷越国境`, which has a rather negative meaning to me, is that OK?

Comment: @Reynaldi the difference between 试图 and 企图 is that 企图 is kind of plan and acting it in planning, but might not really put it into practice, while 试图 connotes you are trying it by acting it.

Comment: 尝试 seems to be the most generally applicable (in particular to everyday activities) whereas 试图 may apply to more complicated/strenuous activities requiring a greater level of preparation or effort, 试图 does not necessarily have a negative connotation, cf. (bkrs) 他们试图摆脱困境。攀登者试图寻出一条通到山顶的新路线。作家试answering comment #2: 图摹写落日的光彩。他试图缓和紧张的气氛.

also note (as in E) 尝试 may apply to tasting food: syn. 尝尝, 品, 品尝, 品味

Comment: I would imagine `努力` do sth. would be the most colloquial translation of `to try` here.

Comment: @user3306356♦ "努力" would work too, but I think "recovering the torn photo (from one's hands)" does not need a great amount of effort to do and sounds rather odd to me if it is used. "努力" sounds too strong for me in terms of doing an action. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Reynaldi I think in Chinese logic the idea of `to try` something is very rarely used the same as it is in the English context. Words like *试着* are hardly ever heard in daily spoken language. If anything it would just be directly stated what the person was doing. I think Semaphore's answer is a good example of what even these "try" words actually mean - to plan, to experiment, etc. Even in English the synonyms of `to try` include: `make an effort, exert oneself`. By this logic no one would need to **try** to "recover a torn photo (from one's hands)" - they would just do it. "努力" seems closest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**嘗試** means simply "to try" or "have tried". For example,

> "Try something new" => **嘗試**新事物

**試圖** is synonymous with 打算, and means "planning to do something". It can be translated as "try" or "attempt", but implies more of a plan. For example,

> "Trying to write a book." => **試圖**寫本書.

**企圖** has the same meaning with 試圖, but with a negative connotation. For example,

> "Planning to rob the bank." => **企圖**搶銀行

For your case, both 她 嘗試 / 試圖 修復被撕毀的照片 can be acceptable. If she has not yet begun working on the photo, 試圖 sounds most natural. If she's already in the act, I would suggest  **正**試圖 or **正在**嘗試. If she has already finished, go with 嘗試.

Answer (score 3):

嘗試 (v) to try (one's hand at)

試圖 (v) attempt to /seek to

企圖 (v) plan to /intend to ; (n) plan/ intention

"她**嘗試**修復被撕碎的照片。means "she **tries her hand** at restore the torn picture." (she actually acts upon her intention)

"她**試圖**修復被撕碎的照片。means "she **attempts to** restore the torn picture."  (using 試圖 imply the action is either unlikely to success or not supposed to be carried out)

"她**企圖**修復被撕碎的照片。means "she **plan to** restore the torn picture." (using 企圖 also imply the action is either unlikely to success or not supposed to be carried out; but with a more deliberate and determined mindset than 試圖)

Comment: Do you mean that "企圖" indicates the action is just "a plan"? Is the action not happened yet? I see the first two sentences indicates that the action is already occurred (i.e. already took an attempt) based on your translation.

Comment: 企圖 only stated 'plan to' , the action itself may or may not had occurred. For example: "Pepsi builds a large factory in China 企圖 take over Coca-Cola's leading role in soft-drink market" -- The act of building a large factory showed it 企圖 (plan to) defeat Coco-Cola. On the other hand, if Pepsi just making all kind of plans but yet to carry out any of them, it is still 企圖 (plan) to defeat Coca-Cola. 企圖 itself is the action of 'to plan'. In 企圖修復,  there's no mention of the action of 修復  has or has not been carried out. It can be either way.

Comment: I see. So you're saying that "企圖" is used to emphasize that the plan of an action is more solid / well-planned compared to "試圖"?

Comment: "企圖" is used to emphasize a 'deliberate plan' or  a 'strong intention' (expecting to fulfill an objective)

Answer (score 2):

她嘗試修復被撕碎的照片。

她試圖修復被撕碎的照片。

她企圖修復被撕碎的照片。

The first sentence is appropriate to interpret the English sentence you quote.

試圖 and 企圖 connote one's intention, pursue something. 企圖 has negative meanings sometimes. It sounds you plan something that will benefit you from others.

By the way, there is a mistake in your sentence. 被碎 should be 被撕碎.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, much appreciated. If you said that "試圖" expresses one's intention, shouldn't the second sentence also valid?

Comment: @Reynaldi you can, but the second one implies that the speaker think it's very hard or impossible to fix the torn pic, so the effort of trying might be in vain  from his opinion. Your original English sentence doesn't have that connotation, hence sentence one is the best fit.