# Difference between 須要 vs 需要 and 嘗試 vs 試試看?

Tags: grammar

1) What's the difference between 須要 and 需要? Are they interchangeable?

2) [This question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/what-is-the-difference-between-%E5%98%97%E8%A9%A6-%E8%A9%A6%E5%9C%96-and-%E4%BC%81%E5%9C%96) illustrates the differences among 嘗試，試圖， and 企圖, but omits 試試看. Can someone explain how 試試看 differs from 嘗試?

Comment: for 須要，需要 see previous Q & A (search site using e.g. "須要，需要") https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%bf%85%e9%a1%bb-%e5%be%97-and-%e9%9c%80%e8%a6%81/22010#22010 for '試試看 see verb reduplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'須要' (need to) applies to 'verb' e.g. '須要付錢' (need to pay)

'需要' (need) applies to 'noun' e.g. '需要金錢' (need money)

'試試看 means 'try and see' e.g. '**試試看**不付账单' (**try** not to pay the bill **and see**); '加些糖**試試看**' (**try** add some sugar **and see**)

*If you remove 看 and write '試試' then it would become reduplication of '試' (try/ test) ; 試試 = 'slightly try/ test a little '*

'嘗試' means  'to try (one's hand at)' As stated in the other question.

Comment: '須要' is redundant. A simple '須' will do the job.

Comment: I think not, '須要付錢' (need to pay) shortened to  '須付錢' just  wouldn't sound colloquial at all.

Comment: Actually 須要 can be shortened to  須 or 要, for example '每月均須付費' ((literary) ; '每個月都要付錢' (colloquial)

Comment: would it be wrong to say 需要付錢? this page suggests 需要 is also a verb: https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/sentsearch.php?word=%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81

Comment: @Crashalot 需要(v) applies to noun ; 須要(v) applies to verb; you can say 需要錢, but not 須要錢; you can say 須要付錢, but not 需要付錢; 需要 can be a noun for 'need'. For example  in "有去中國的需要" - '有' is the verb, '去中國的' is the adjective phrase  and '需要' is the noun

Answer (score 0):

须要 is always used as 要， so in daily communication，we Chinese don't use 须要。